# Usage of Lucene in multi JVM Readers and a IndexWriter in separate JVM

Tags: lucene, distributed-computing

How can we use Lucene in multi JVM design.

E.g we have one JVM holding the responsibility of writing to an index (as there can't be multiple writers to same index).

Now we have 400 different client JVMs which are trying to read data from the index.

I have implemented a single IndexServer JVM for writing to index.
And provide the reader api in every client JVM i.e. every client JVM is opening the IndexSearcher/Reader to read from same index.

Frequency of writes is 20K docs (plain text lines) per minute, (500 files / min)
Frequency of reads is 20K docs per 5mins.

WE are facing serious latency problems both in reader and writer. Index size builds from 0 to 8 GB and Read and writes happens in parallel.

Any clues on what is going wrong here.

Comment: There's too much guesswork to do; but only profiling will show the actual hotspots. My guess is that lots of writer time is spent merging and reader is suffering because of poor cacheability. By the way, from your description it looks like you have reinvented Solr or Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yeah kind-of poor man's Solr. Wanted to understand how people normally use Lucene in multi jvm distributed architecture.<BR> Yes the readers are slow because we create a new Reader instance per read request, as we can cache them because the writer is inserting in the index constantly in separate JVM. How can we efficiently keep IndexSearcher(s) in multiple jvm in synch with IndexWriter is separate JVM.

Comment: Yeah kind-of poor man's Solr. Wanted to understand how people normally use Lucene in multi jvm distributed architecture.<BR> Yes the readers are slow because we create a new Reader instance per read request, as we can't cache them because the writer is inserting in the index constantly in separate JVM. How can we efficiently keep IndexSearcher(s) in multiple jvm in synch with IndexWriter is separate JVM.

Comment: But do you really *need* to keep searchers in separate JVMs? Why not have a single server (or few identical clones) which would benefit from caching?

Comment: One jvm both for indexing and searching might not be enough for us looking at the number of concurrent clients we may start facing too many connections issues on single server and fault tolerancy would also be an issues.. How can we do cloning here, I understand there can't be multiple writers on to same index.. So how does cloning works here? Wouldn't the cloned instance create another writer?

Comment: There can be multiple threads accessing the same `IndexWriter`, it will perfectly handle that (up to a poing of course). Regarding cloning - you should be looking at [SolrCloud](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) or relevant bits on Elasticsearch which are addressing this problem. For a quick remedy, you could check if you are using [NRT reader](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html) which will benefit from some caching.

Comment: I would consider using ElasticSearch to support the multiple JVM's.